# how to find the interrupt source code in linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, timestamp, interrupt

I am looking for source code of interrupt service routine and searching net_bhi(); and netif_rx(); interrupt routine in the linux kernel. The above both api are the packet receiving of udp in the linux kernel. I want to modify interrupt routine as - I should calculate the timestamp when the interrupt occurs. So please someone help where is the location for the above file ??

Answer (score 2):

Each network device (driver, really: the software that knows how to operate the device) will have its own interrupt service routine. The driver registers that routine's address with request_irq (in essence, "when this interrupt fires, call me here").

In the case of a network driver, the driver's interrupt routine will typically do little other than invoke a tasklet or softirq. This is to avoid running for long periods of time in a state that may block other critical interrupts.

In most modern network drivers, a softirq is actually triggered through a framework called NAPI. The driver will have registered its NAPI poll routine with netif_napi_add, and at interrupt time, the driver calls napi_schedule to communicate that its poll routine needs to run.

Once its tasklet or NAPI poll routine is invoked, the driver will access device registers to see why the device interrupted. If new packets are available, the driver will usually forward them to the linux TCP/IP stack with netif_rx or a variant thereof.

So, you'll have to choose where/how to record your timestamp. It would be easiest to do so in the tasklet or NAPI poll routine, but that may be some (possibly many) microseconds after the packet actually arrived. (Some delay between packet arrival and timestamp recording will be unavoidable in any case without specialized hardware.)

Comment: Good explanation @gil-hamilton
One question though, how can I figure out the irq number to be used in request_irq(), where is the source of those numbers?
Thanks!

Comment: There is no single answer to that. However, the most common case you'll see is for PCI devices; there, the irq number comes from a `struct pci_dev` associated with the device. That interrupt number is chosen by the kernel and assigned to the device as part of the initial bus enumeration. In the case of MSI, or MSIX, the driver has to request additional interrupt numbers as part of its initialization.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the path. But you must find it in /usr/src/linux-...

But if you want to have a time stamp printed with the interrupt, you can actually catch the interrupt using signal handlers, and then use gettimeofday() API to print the time.

Comment: I am already inside the /usr/src/linux version   but I dont know where exactly is it ?? I am using in the kernel  as now = sched_clock(); to get the timestamp. First I need to find the interrupt service routine in the kernel source code.

Comment: Is it not in a loadable kernel module driver?

Comment: could you please specify the path ??